# How to do a git diff <commit>...<working tree>?

Tags: git

It's straightforward to do a `git diff <commit>...<some other commit>`, but how can I achieve something equivalent to specifying "working tree" as the last argument in that command? I've tried `git diff <commit>...`, `git diff <commit>... .`, etc, but they don't actually pick up my changes in the working tree.

Bonus points if `<commit>` can be a remote branch =)

Answer (score 3):

With `...` you are implicitly specifying `HEAD`. You want the single argument version of diff to diff against the working tree.

```
git diff <commit>
```

`<commit>` can be anything that refers to a commit such as the name of a remote-tracking branch.

Comment: It's definitely not worth an own answer: Add, that you can refer a remote branch with `remoteName/branchName` (like in `origin/master`) and that it is possible to see all branches with `git branch -a`.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Yes, I have added a clarification.

Comment: I've tried this, and while it _does_ pick up working tree changes, it doesn't have the filtering that `...` gives you (which simulates what would happen if you called `git-merge-base`)

Comment: @Suan: But you cannot have a merge base with just a working tree; it doesn't have history. Perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? (I've removed the first sentence. You're right; it was incorrect to say it makes _no_ difference with `log`.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey I want to view a diff similar with what Github shows when you go to the /compare URL of a forked repo (changes which have taken place upstream but which are for separate files than what you have changed should not show up in the diff). But yeah, I'm beginning to think git doesn't do sufficient magic for this to be possible, without you committing your working tree changes first...

Comment: @Suan: I don't know what GitHub does, but I can't see how it can compare a working tree.

Comment: @Suan: Are you just looking for `git diff $(git merge-base HEAD <commit>)`? You could always put it in a shell function or git alias.